# SELECT from a list of ids is not returning results

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this piece of sql code that returns me the ids I need to delete

```
(select id FROM payment_method pm
 where 1 != (select count(*) from payment_method pm2 where pm2.user_id = pm.user_id) 
and pm.type = 'WALLET')
EXCEPT  (SELECT 
           id
        FROM
            payment_method
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY user_id , created_at desc)
```

And this gives me a list of ids:

[image: ids]

The ids are correct but when I try to delete the records with those ids, there a 0 results (even if i put select * from payment_method **where id in (...)** does not give any result):

```
DELETE FROM payment_method WHERE id IN
((select id FROM payment_method pm
 where 1 != (select count(*) from payment_method pm2 where pm2.user_id = pm.user_id) 
and pm.type = 'WALLET')
EXCEPT  (SELECT 
           id
        FROM
            payment_method
        GROUP BY user_id
        ORDER BY user_id , created_at desc));
```

Funny thing is that if I put NOT IN, it shows me the rest of the ids, that should not be deleted.
Can you help me?

Comment: except  .. in mysql  ???  which version you are using ???

Comment: This will not provide result/ delete your data. You are using same table with EXCEPT clause

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting to delete\

Comment: I have SELECT something EXCEPT something else
And this gives me a list of ids and I want to delete the records with those ids

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement and tag the question correctly.

Comment: @scaisEdge - MariaDB 10.3 added syntactic sugar for compatibility:  `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT`.

Comment: @MihaiMarius - Use a multi-table `DELETE`; see the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can interpret is that you want to keep only one "WALLET" id for each user -- and that this is the most recent one.  That is not the list of ids that you are coming up with, unless you are just lucky.  But it is my best interpretation of what you could usefully be trying to do.  The `ORDER BY` is the subquery is ignored.

If this is the case, then:

```
DELETE pm
    FROM payment_method pm JOIN
         (SELECT pm2.user_id, MAX(created_at) as max_created_at
          FROM payment_method pm2
          WHERE pm2.type = 'WALLET'
          GROUP BY pm2.user_id
         ) pm2
         ON pm2.user_id = pm.user_id
    WHERE pm.type = 'WALLET' AND
          pm.created_at < pm2.max_created_at;
```